# How to fix outofmemory error in Android?

Tags: java, android, memory, arraylist

We are getting outofmemory error frequently and hence application is getting crashed. Our requirement is like app gets gps location on location change and adds into arraylist. Using this gps data, have used one algorithm to compress gps data compression. 
It runs in every 1 min and executes in thread. But after sometimes memory goes high and i have posted block of code on which i have getting raise out of memory.

Problem is that below for loop unable to execute up to 85 times with its calculations.

---

Please help me to solve this problem.
Does anyone have idea that how can we tackle this issue?

---

```
encodep = new Object[n_point - 1][11];

    double sum_thetalen = 0;
    double sum_t = 0;

    /* initializing sed probability table
     * SED_RESOLUTION=10; 0.1
     * SED_RESOLUTION=100 0.01
     */
    // final double SED_RESOLUTION = 10;
    // double sed_value_count = 1 / (double) (tol_GTAround * SED_RESOLUTION);

    /* encoding starts */
    Log.d(TAG,
            "Encoding start .........................................................................");
    // ProgressNotification.Create(n_point);
    AppPolar ap_new = new AppPolar();
    for (int i = 0; i < (n_point - 1); i++) {
        // ProgressNotification.Notify(i);
        double dxcurr = ap.xapp.get(i + 1) - x_code.get(i);
        double dycurr = ap.yapp.get(i + 1) - y_code.get(i);
        /*if (param.b_debug == 1) {
            System.out.println("ap.tapp.size=" + ap.tapp.size() + " ");
            System.out.println("_t_code=" + t_code.size() + " ");
        }*/

        double tinvcurr = (ap.tapp.get(i + 1) - t_code.get(i));

        ap_new.polar(dxcurr, dycurr, tinvcurr, angcurr, tol_GTA, ratio_tol);
        angcurr = ap_new.angcurr0;
        double app_spd = ap_new.spdapp;
        double tol_spd = ap_new.tol_spd;
        double app_ang = ap_new.angcurr0;
        double app_dang = ap_new.dangapp;
        double tol_dang = ap_new.tol_dang;

        /* Encoding time */
        Log.d(TAG,
                "time Encoding start ........................................................................."
                        + i);
        double dt_codeval = Function.round(tinvcurr / mint_tinterv);
        double sum = Function.sum(prob_t);
        double add_to_sum = delta_dt / maxtsq;
        List<Double> prob_ttmp = new ArrayList<Double>();
        int prob_t_size = prob_t.size();

        for (int index = 0; index < prob_t_size; index++) {
            prob_ttmp.add((prob_t.get(index) / sum) + add_to_sum);
        }

        sum = 1 / Function.sum(prob_ttmp);

        prob_ttmp = Function.multiplyBy(prob_ttmp, sum);
        dt_code.add(mint_tinterv * dt_codeval);
        t_code.add(t_code.get(i) + dt_code.get(i));

        encodep[i][0] = Function.cloneList(prob_ttmp);
        encodep[i][1] = dt_codeval;

        encodep[i][2] = -Math.log(prob_ttmp.get((int) dt_codeval - 1)) / Math.log(2D);
        sum_t = sum_t + (Double) encodep[i][2];
        prob_t = Function.multiplyBy(prob_t, gamma_dt);
        prob_t.set((int) (dt_codeval - 1), prob_t.get((int) (dt_codeval - 1)) + 1);

        prob_ttmp.clear();
        prob_ttmp = null;

        Log.d(TAG,
                "time Encoding stop ........................................................................."
                        + i);

        /* Encoding speed */
        Log.d(TAG,
                "speed Encoding start ........................................................................."
                        + i);

        spd_code.add(app_spd);
        double codindtmp = Function.round(app_spd / tol_spd) + 1;
        int maxspdind = (int) Math.ceil(maxspd / tol_spd) + 1;

        if (i == 0) {
            prob_spdtmp = Function.populateList(1D / maxspdind, maxspdind);
        }
        else {
            Double tpre = (double) t_code.get(i);

            double dttmp = t_spdmean;
            double dtmax = (dt.get(i) * trt_spd);
            if (dttmp < dtmax)
                dttmp = dtmax;
            int sqtmp = 0;
            int tappSize = ap.tapp.size();
            for (int j = 0; j < tappSize; j++) {
                if (ap.tapp.get(j) >= tpre - dttmp) {
                    sqtmp = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (sqtmp > (i - t_minseg))
                sqtmp = i - (int) t_minseg;
            if (sqtmp < 0)
                sqtmp = 0;

            estimatorSpeedMeanSig(spd_code.subList(sqtmp, i), dt_code.subList(sqtmp, i + 1),
                    param);

            List<Double> spdlist = Function
                    .populateList1(0, tol_spd, (maxspdind - 1) * tol_spd);

            List<Double> gausspdftmp = new ArrayList<Double>();

            int spdlistSize = spdlist.size();
            for (int index = 0; index < spdlistSize; index++) {
                gausspdftmp.add(Math.exp(-0.5 * ((spdlist.get(index) - estspd) / estspdvar)
                        * (spdlist.get(index) - estspd) / estspdvar)
                        / ((Math.sqrt(2 * Math.PI) * estspdvar)));
            }

            gausspdftmp = Function.multiplyBy(gausspdftmp, 1D / Function.sum(gausspdftmp));
            prob_spdtmp = Function.add(gausspdftmp, delta_speed / maxspdind);
            prob_spdtmp = Function.multiplyBy(prob_spdtmp, 1D / Function.sum(prob_spdtmp));

            spdlist.clear();
            spdlist = null;

            gausspdftmp.clear();
            gausspdftmp = null;
            Log.d(TAG,
                    "speed Encoding stop ........................................................................."
                            + i);
        }// else
        Log.d(TAG,
                "Encoding stop .........................................................................");
```

Comment: Hard to tell without any code. I assume you're creating some memory leak with the android API.

Comment: There are 4-5 classes which runs in constructor.

Comment: Could you post some of the code where you interact with the android API? How large is the arraylist with the data when the app crashes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **android:largeHeap="true"** in manifest file to request a larger heap size, but this will not work on any pre Honeycomb devices. On pre 2.3 devices, you can use the VMRuntime class, but this will not work on Gingerbread and above.

Comment: This is not a proper fix. It will only increase the time until the crash when there is a memory leak.

Comment: you have to use square libray https://github.com/square/leakcanary  to check that where memory leak and fixed issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should seek for memory leeks. This is hard work, but you can do first in Android Studio:
- open DDMS, 
- click on your package name,
- start allocation tracking, make some activity in your app
- in generated file you can see how many object have reference to other objects or which from are accessible.

Probably you can have memory leak while activity pause/resume  or after screen rotation (some retained activity reference from async task etc) or simply you use too much large bitmaps (which should be scaled down, like there http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)